# Reasoning ( CSIR NET December 2015)

Tags: logic

This question was asked in CSIR NET December 2015. I could not solve this question.Although I know the answer that CSIR posted in their answer key, which is 2. But I cannot understand how 2 is the correct option.
Please help to solve this question.

The statement: “**The father of my son is the only child of your parents**”

1. can never be true
2. is true in only one type of relation
3. can be true for more than one type of relations
4. can be true only in a polygamous family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaker is a mother and the father is being spoken to if we disregard other sexual orientations.

Suppose $x$ is the speaker and $y$ is being spoken to. $x$ must be a parent. Suppose $x$ is the father. Then $x$ is referring to himself as he says "father of my son". So $x$ is the only child of $y$'s parents i.e. $x=y$ and $x$ is talking to himself. Therefore $x$ can't be the father $\implies x$ is the mother. Now the only child of $y$'s parents is $y$. So $y$ is the father.

Comment: That is well and good, though sexual orientation doesn't really come into it as long as the son has exactly one father. The greater problem is how the questioner imagines relations to be classified into "types" here. It appears that "a polygamous family" counts as a "type of relation", and the statement can certainly be true there (one man, at least two women, speaker is one of the women) -- but it can _also_ be true in a traditional nuclear family, so based on that it is hard to escape **(3)** being the right answer rather than (2).

Comment: I referred to sexual orientation just to be able to use the usual terminology of mother, father etc. I think relation here refers to the relation between the speaker and the listener rather than family structure. So in a polygamous family the relation would still be ''husband-wife" if we disregard divorced parents.

Comment: so the answer is 2 -- The statement is true in only one relationship..@Jack'swastedlife

Answer (score 0):

"The father of my son" Is equivalent to "myself" So the statement is "Myself is the only child of your parents".
That person is talking to himself. So, It is true only one type of relation. )(A kind of Reflexive relation.)